# application fails when more than one activity calls startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I have 2 activities that call a third activity using startActivityForResult but after the third activity finishes the application fails before onActivityResult is called.  When I initially had only 1 activity calling it, it worked fine and if I use the debugger it works, which usually means something is uninitialized.  My code is as follows:

Activity A:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ActivityA.this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_CATEGORY);
    }
});

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == ADD_CATEGORY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getCharSequenceExtra("Added") != null) {
            String category = data.getCharSequenceExtra("Added").toString();
            categoryList.add(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ActivityB.this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_ITEM);
    }
});

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);       
    if (requestCode == ADD_ITEM && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String item = data.getCharSequenceExtra("Added").toString();
        if (currentList == null) {
            currentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        currentList.add(item);
        Collections.sort(currentList);
    }
}
```

Activity C:

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                  // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                  if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode ==       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                      // Return added item to the calling activity
                      Intent intent = new Intent();
                      CharSequence text = edittext.getText();
                      intent.putExtra("Added", text);
                      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                      finish();
                      return true;
                  }
                  return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or could this be an Android bug?

Comment: Can you place the error log please? and format onclicklistener as code :)

Comment: What does `logcat` say about the crash? Can you include the crash dump?

Comment: Nothing shows up in logcat.  Do I need to turn something on?  I don't think there is a crash dump either.  Sorry, I'm new to Android and Eclipse so I'm just figuring things out as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if(data != null && data.hasExtra("Added")){` inside your `onActivityResult` functions to verify that there is actually a `data` variable passed back. If the user hits the back button it will return to the previous Activity but `data` will be null in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I will add the check for null data to handle the back button case but don't think that's the problem I'm seeing because I actually typed in some text and when I hit the Enter key the application just failed.  A message comes up saying the process stopped working.

Comment: I also know onActivityResult didn't get called because I put in a Toast call at the beginning and it didn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your are setting the result in `AddActivity` as per your activity call...show your logcat..

Answer (score 0):

While it may be unlikely in this case, its always worth mentioning:

Possibly the most common reason for extras not being set by activities started with startActivityForResult is that they are **SingleTask** activities.

All activities that are run in their own task will result in onActivityResult() being called with RESULT_OK before the new activity even starts.

Calls to setResult() in SingleTask activities are pointless and will not do anything useful.